# clusters proc -try to converting sas to R-

Tags: r, sas

i have allready tried to convert sas to R : the purpose- 3 group of cities with low var in groups and high var between groups

```
proc standard data=data m=0 std=1 out=varst_scst; 
var x; 
run;
proc sort data=varst_scst; by x; run;

proc cluster data=varst_scst method=ward rmsstd ccc p=3 
              outtree=tree; var score; id shem; run;
proc tree data=tree noprint out=clus n=3; copy score; run;
proc sort data=clus; by score; run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It is hard to help you without data.  Can you share the data you are working with or use a dataset that ships with R?

Try this:

```
scaled.dat <- scale(theData) # standardize
d <- dist(scaled.dat, method = "euclidean") # distance matrix
fit <- hclust(d, method="ward") # cluster
plot(fit) # display dendogram
groups <- cutree(fit, k=3) # cut tree into 3 clusters
# draw dendogram with red borders around the 3 clusters
rect.hclust(fit, k=3, border="red")
```

If that gives you what you need click the green checkmark. If not, ask more questions (and give us data to work with).

Comment: City             sviut_razon_haim zipiot baayot bdidut aflaya
Ashdod                  86.9          55.2 73.3          20.5 21.6
Ashkelon                  82.6          54.5 77.1          26.1 
Beer sheva           90.6          54.0 69.6   24.4          25.2